# Can a Go program read from the keyboard when stdin is something else?

Tags: go, pipe, stdin

I have a Go process that accepts input via pipe.

> tail -f something.foo | go run myprog.go

Since stdin is the output of the pipe, I can't find a way to read keyboard input in myprog.go.  Is this possible?

I considered executing the tail command inside of myprog.go, but I want to avoid creating another process in the event myprog.go crashes and fails to terminate the other one.

Comment: It's not about Go exactly. Maybe named pipes FIFO(7) (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) can help?

Comment: Perhaps use `/dev/fd3` as a channel? Not tried but something like that: `tail ... 1>&3 | go run ...` and then open `/dev/fd3` for tail input and stdin for keyboard. I have no idea if this works, but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On linux (and POSIX in general), you can open `/dev/tty` to get the input to the controlling tty for your process.

```
func readStdin() {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := os.Stdin.Read(buf)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Print("FROM STDIN:", string(buf[:n]))
        if err == io.EOF {
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    go readStdin()

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    tty, err := os.Open("/dev/tty")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer tty.Close()
    for {
        n, err := tty.Read(buf)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Print("FROM TTY:", string(buf[:n]))
        if err == io.EOF {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Which can output:

```
$ echo HELLO | ./tty_reader
FROM STDIN:HELLO
typing on my keyboard
FROM TTY:typing on my keyboard
```

Comment: It's not just Linux; the other Unix systems work fine with this too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the shell to create a pipe for you to feed input to your program while leaving stdin free for other things. Something to the sound of

```
go run myprog.go <(tail -f something.foo)
```

The shell will execute `tail` and redirect it's stdout to a new fifo. Your program receives the fifo as first argument, pointing to `/proc/self/fd/1234567`

Comment: This is *extremely* shell specific (bash only?).